# Jquery/ajax web service call get redirected (302 Object moved) and then 500 unknown webservice name

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I have been struggling with this for some times.. I searched around but didn't get a solution yet. This is only an issue on production server. In my development environment, everything works just fine.

I am using JQuery/Ajax to update product information based on product's Color attribute. for example, a product has A and B color, the price for color A is different from color B.
When user choose different color, the price information is updated as well.

What I did is to first add a javascript function:
 `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">`

```
function updateProductVariant() {
                var myval = jQuery("#<%=colorDropDownList.ClientID%>").val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Products.aspx/GetVariantInfoById",
                    data: "{variantId:'" + myval + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (response) {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d);

                        jQuery("#<%=lblStockAvailablity.ClientID%>").text(obj.StockMessage);
                        jQuery(".price .productPrice").text(obj.CurrentPrice);
                        jQuery(".price .oldProductPrice").text(obj.OldPrice);
                    }

                });
            }
```

Then I can register the dropdown list's 'onclick' event point to function 'updateProductVariant'

```
GetVariantInfoById is a Web method in the codebehind, its also very straightforward：
    [WebMethod]
        public static string GetVariantInfoById(string variantId)
        {

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(variantId);

        ProductVariant productVariant = IoC.Resolve<IProductService>().GetProductVariantById(id);

        string stockMessage = productVariant.FormatStockMessage();

        StringBuilder oBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        oBuilder.Append("{");
        oBuilder.AppendFormat(@"""{0}"":""{1}"",", "StockMessage", stockMessage);
        oBuilder.AppendFormat(@"""{0}"":""{1}"",", "OldPrice", PriceHelper.FormatPrice(productVariant.OldPrice));
        oBuilder.AppendFormat(@"""{0}"":""{1}""", "CurrentPrice", PriceHelper.FormatPrice(productVariant.Price));
        oBuilder.Append("}");
        return oBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

All these works fine on my local box, but if i upload to the production server, catching the traffic using fiddler, /Products.aspx/GetVariantInfoById becomes a 302 
Object moved

### Object moved to [here](http://www.pocomaru.com/Products.aspx/GetVariantInfoById/default.aspx).

On my local box,

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0

Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2011 09:00:08 GMT

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 117
Connection: Close

But when deployed on the host, it becomes
HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 186

Via: 1.1 ADV-TMG-01

Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2011 08:59:12 GMT

Location: http://www.pocomaru.com/Products.aspx/GetVariantInfoById/default.aspx

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

then of course, then it returns 500 error title>Unknown web method GetVariantInfoById/default.aspx.
Parameter name: methodName

Can someone please take a look? I think its some configuration in the production server which automatically redirects my webservice call to some other URL, but since the product server is out of my control, i am seeking a local fix for this.